# Any simple way to test null before convert an object to string

Tags: java, null

I always write

```
Object o;
if (o!=null)
String s = o.toString();
```

If there simple way to handle this case?

Comment: short answer no. (could use some third party lib that abstracts the nullcheck)

Comment: Maybe a better idea would be to avoid `o` being `null` in the first place.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`ObjectUtils.toString(object)` from commons-lang. The code there is actually one line:

```
return obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();
```

Just one note - use `toString()` only for debug and logging. Don't rely on the format of `toString()`.

Comment: The method `ObjectUtils.toString(object)` is deprecated since Java 7 in favor of `java.util.Objects.toString(Object)` and will be removed in future releases. Note however that said method will return "null" for null references, while this method returns and empty String. To preserve behavior use `java.util.Objects.toString(myObject, "")` as is also mentioned in other answers below.

Answer (score 118):

The static `valueOf` method in the `String` class will do the null check and return `"null"` if the object is `null`:

```
String stringRepresentation = String.valueOf(o);
```

Comment: If "null" is ok, you can also use `String stringRepresentation = "" + o;`, saw Peter Lawrey's answer after commenting...

Answer (score 94):

Try `Objects.toString(Object o, String nullDefault)`

Example:

```
import java.util.Objects;

Object o1 = null;
Object o2 = "aString";
String s;

s = Objects.toString(o1, "isNull"); // returns "isNull"
s = Objects.toString(o2, "isNull"); // returns "aString"
```

Comment: Is it really simplier than the way the question's author checks?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the context. As a null safe single statement it can make a piece of code shorter and simpler to read if used appropriately.

Comment: Note: This only became available in Java 7

Comment: I prefer this solution since it is the most explicit one and easy to read. If someone uses `ObjectUtils.toString` or `String.valueOf` you must always read the JavaDoc to see what will be returned in case the given argument is `null`. Thanks for this one!

Comment: The goodness of this method is that I can do `Objects.toString(o1, null);` instead of `o1 != null ? o1.toString() : null`. Maybe it's not obvious why the first is better than the second, but it's because `o1` is short var name, but when it is long expression with method chains, the difference become obvious.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Who in their right mind wants "null" as a result?

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.util.Objects;
Objects.toString(object, "")
```

Simple and 0 runtime exception :)

Comment: or use just: `Objects.toString(object)` wihtout `nullDefault` parameter. This method return `object.toString()` or `null`

Comment: @Ralph "This method return `object.toString()` or `null`". The important fact here is when the object is `null` this method actually returns **a string**, containing text "null". Not a `null` reference. This method basically delegates to `String.valueOf(object)`.

Comment: @ Ruslan Stelmachenk: right, it return the string `"null"` but not the value `null`, if you want to have a null value, you need to use `Objects.toString(object, null)`

Comment: Under does String.valueOf(..). Why not use directly valueOf ?!

Answer (score 12):

**Updated answer of Bozho and January-59 for reference:**

`ObjectUtils.toString(object)` from commons-lang. The code there is actually one line:

```
return obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();
```

However this method in Apache Commons is now *deprecated* since release 3.2 (commons/lang3). Their goal here was to remove all the methods that are available in Jdk7. The method has been replaced by `java.util.Objects.toString(Object)` in **Java 7** and will probably be removed in future releases. After some discussion they did not remove it yet (currently in 3.4) and it is still available as a deprecated method.

**Note however that said java 7+ method will return "null" for null references, while this method returns and empty String. To preserve behavior use**

```
java.util.Objects.toString(myObject, "")
```

Comment: How is this even a relevant answer when the question is specifically talking about `null` and not `"null"` ?

Answer (score 7):

`String.valueOf(o)` returns the string "null" if o is null.

Another one could be `String s = o == null? "default" : o.toString()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use java 8 Optional in the following way:

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(o).map(Object::toString).orElse("null");
```

Comment: You can avoid the overhead of a second `Optional` generated by `map()` by using `Optional.ofNullable(o).orElse("null").toString();` instead.

Comment: Yes, also possible

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want it to on a `null` value but you can just do this

```
Object o =
String s = ""+o;
```

This is the default behaviour for println and string append etc.

Comment: but this returns "null" if o is null, this doesn't look like what the question is about.

Comment: @jan you could be right.  the behaviour of `s` when `o` is null isn't defined in the question.  It is simpler however, if it is appropriate.

Comment: This is a good way to go in case you're writing to some kind of log output for instance.

Comment: @av_lee it is the simplest.  If you are logging, then the speed of the operation is unlikely to matter.  However, if performance is critical, you are better off not using a String at all. i.e. `String.vallueOf` is neither the shorter, simplest nor fastest alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want get a String when o is not a NULL.
But I'm confusing that if coding like yours you can't access variable s (you know s in scope of if statement).